# What formula can I use to remove special characters and white space once data is pasted

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a marketing spreadsheet. Sometimes when we copy and paste a phone number or an address and it has special characters such as "(" "." "#" etc. I would like to remove these.

I Have attached a sample of the sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jXZV1vkFSZXx1YgPmdNAd7u8lCG27uY-nJZxhvy48Qs/edit?usp=sharing).

I've tried using Regex however for the phone number when there are certain symbols I get an error.

I would like to paste the phone number or address from our sources into a google sheet and for the sheet to automatically remove the special characters while maintaining the original order of the numbers or text. I was thinking of some array formula hidden in the header maybe?

Comment: your sheet is empty

Comment: Added data now. my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
={"arrayformula here"; ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(C2:C&"", "[^0-9]*", ))}
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Using `REGEXREPLACE` we can try:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "[^0-9-]+","")
```

This would remove any character from the phone number *other* than a digit or dash.

Comment: Can I turn this into a formula where it's hidden in the header or a row so that once data gets pasted in the cell, it automatically formats it into the proper format and removes the unwanted characters?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to do this using Google Sheets.